# Relative priorities for line breaks between certain words in a phrase

Tags: line-breaking, penalty, sentence, wordbreak

Let's assume we wish to typeset

> message sequence chart (MSC)

We interpret this phrase as a (computer-science) term followed by its abbreviation in parens. Further, we interpret the term “message sequence chart” as “sequence chart of messages”. Thus, we prefer that line breaks, should they get necessary, be chosen as follows:

> message [secondary choice] sequence [tertiary choice] chart [primary choice] (MSC)

Of course, the quaternary choice for the line breaks is inside the words.  Now, how do we tell our choices to LaTeX? I'm thinking of

```
message\penalty-1\ sequence chart\penalty-2\ (MSC)
```

or

```
message sequence\penalty1\ chart\penalty-1\ (MSC)
```

or

```
message\penalty1\ sequence\penalty2\ chart (MSC)
```

Which one should it be?  Is the blank `\`  the proper space, or should we say `\hskip<whatever> plus<whatever> minus<whatever>` , and if so, with which numbers?

Moreover, if the sentence starts right before “message”, our wish, clearly, is

> [primary choice] Message [tertiary choice] sequence [quaternary choice] chart [secondary choice] (MSC)

the quinary choice being inside the words. How do we set the penalties in this case?

If the sentence terminates right after “(MSC)”, our wish, clearly, is

> message [tertiary choice] sequence [quaternary choice] chart [secondary choice] (MSC). [primary choice]

the quinary choice being inside the words again. How do we set the penalties in this case?

Here's some MWE for you to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
%\showoutput% I found no use of it
\begin{document}
message sequence chart (MSC)
\end{document}
```

We use both `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, so whatever you do should work with both engines.

Comment: There is \linebreak[3], but it rarely does anything.  It might be easier to just put an \hbox around the words where you want to prevent a break.

Comment: @JohnKormylo We sometimes have long paragraphs. There, even small differences in `\penalty` values matter, but I have no idea which values are, well, proper™.

Comment: 0 : penalty = 0
1 : penalty = \@lowpenalty,
2 : penalty = \@medpenalty 
3 : penalty = \@highpenalty 
4 : penalty = 10000

Comment: it will be vanishingly rare that making penalty differences of  <10 at  word endings is going to make any difference.

Comment: @JohnKormylo With the nonnegative preferences you suggested (as well as with any nonnegative preferences), I'm afraid that LaTeX would discourage breaking inside “message sequence chart (MSC)” *relatively* to breaking outside this phrase. Or am I wrong on this? What do you think?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle We have around 500 pages in one book and around 500 pages in another one. We have stuff not only in the main text, but also in the margins and narrow table columns. With lots of text, the differences may show up.

Comment: Instead of an \hbox, you could connect the words with `~` instead of a space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is very true if we wish to prevent a line break at particular places altogether (which is not the case).

Comment: @AlbertNash you may (with difficulty) find an example that makes a difference but so hard to make an example and so many other factors involved that it really makes no sense to look for general rules for penalty values here. I'll put an example in a cw

Comment: you use the standard penalties John showed negated or not via `\linebreak[2]` v `\nolinebreak[2]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle E.g., `message sequence\nolinebreak[2] chart\linebreak[2] (MSC)` in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: @AlbertNash yes (but `\linebreak` for negative penalty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example here allowing you to experiment with different values. In ths example (which is typical) no value other than -10000 (forced break) makes any difference.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifx\directlua\undefined
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\addtolength\textheight{15\baselineskip}
\addtolength\topmargin{-5\baselineskip}

\def\qq{message\penalty\pA\ sequence chart\penalty\pB\ (MSC) }

\begin{document}

\def\qqq{

\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
Red yellow blue.
\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
Red yellow blue black green.
\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq

One two three \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
One two three \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
One two three \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
One two three four five six \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
One two three \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
One two three \qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq\qq
}

\def\pA{-1}
\def\pB{-2}
\qqq

\clearpage

\def\pA{-1}
\def\pB{-9999}
\qqq

\clearpage

\def\pA{-1}
\def\pB{-10000}
\qqq

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx! So at least, your answer implicitly says that `\ ` is the proper™ way to typeset a space after `\penalty<whatever>`.

Comment: @AlbertNash yes `\ ` makes  a normal stretchy space

Comment: As for your tests “no value other than -10000 (forced break) makes any difference.”, I trust you.  I've just tested myself some values in [-2,2]∩ℤ and, indeed, no difference as of now. Thx!